# What is the correct way to have different designs for Portrait and Landscape in ViewController?

Tags: ios, storyboard, orientation

Correct way to have different designs for Portrait and Landscape in ViewController, specific designs, no resizing elements, no autolayout, with storyboards. Please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the Apple documentation on [Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW14).